# mongoid equivalent of loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

In a Rails app, using ActiveRecord with mysql, you can check to see if an association has been loaded:

```
class A
    belongs_to :b

a = A.find(...
a.b.loaded? # returns whether the associated object has been loaded
```

Is there an equivalent in mongoid?  ._loaded?  used to work but no longer does.

UPDATE - adding example

```
class A
    include Mongoid::Document
end

class B
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :a
end

a = A.new
b = B.new
b.a = a
b.a._loaded?
```

returns:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a enumerable method of this Class: Mongoid::Relations::Targets::Enumerable

```
_loaded?
```

it will return true and false if Has the enumerable been _loaded? This will be true if the criteria has been executed or we manually load the entire thing.

Comment: thanks Uprenda for your answer, but this used to work, as I noted in my original post, but no longer does, please see my updated question for example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the purpose was not the same.
Now (Mongoid 7.0) **_loaded?()** is a private method, and in my case it always returns true.

The best I could find is **ivar()**: it returns the object if already loaded, or false if not loaded.

I'm not sure if this is a reliable solution. It depends on further availability of ivar() and the way objects are stored as instance variables.

```
> b = B.find('xxx')
  => (db request for "b")
> b.ivar('a')
  => false
> b.a
  => (db request for "a")
> b.ivar('a')
  => (returns "a" object, as when b.a is called)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if includes(:your_association) has been added to the criteria like this:

```
inclusions = Criteria.inclusions.map(&:class_name)
inclusions.include?('YourAssociation)
```

For example:

```
Children.all.include(:parent).inclusions
=> [<Mongoid::Association::Referenced::BelongsTo:0x00007fce08c76040
  @class_name="Parent", ...]

Children.all.inclusions
=> []
```